# Start Telegram Bot via inline keyboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

**How to Start Telegram Bot via inline keyboard?**

**Code:**

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, async  msg => {
    const opts = {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{
                    text: `telegram.me/fullmovie_bot?start=${msg.chat.id}`,
                    callback_data: ``
                }]
            ]
        }
    };
await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Share and Start my Bot`, opts);
});
```

With this code nothing happens
[image: Photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `url` as parameter, see following instance:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]